# jQuery - Capturing HEX color strings

Tags: jquery, regex

I need help for a little task. I have a configuration file where I have to get the specified HEX color code:

```
; List of colors to use for
; the cards in the game
; Colour Memory

#3be6c4     
#e6e03b
#6f3be6 ; This purple shade could be nicer...
#4fe63b
#e63b3b 
#ff5a00 
#ff00de
#3b8fe6
```

On my jQuery code, I know how to read the data from the file, but what I need now is to take ONLY the HEX codes (cutting out blank lines and comments), and put each one into an array. It's a regex matter I guess, but I'm kind of stocked :D

Many thanks

Comment: `'#abcedef'.match(/^(#[a-z0-9]{6})/)[0]` --> "#abcede"

Comment: @Brian, `/#[a-f0-9]{6}/i` matches hex, `a-z` is most certainly incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ECuux/1/

Uses this regex: `/\b[0-9A-F]{6}\b/gi`

The basic code I used:

> var configFile; // Your file as a string
>
> configFile.match(/\b[0-9A-F]{6}\b/gi)

Comment: I've just edited your regex by adding the "#" character, like that /#\b[0-9A-F]{6}\b/gi

Answer (score 2):

use `/#[0-9a-f]{6}/ig` as the regular expression, no need for jquery as it can all be easily done without the library.

```
var data = "your file data here";
hexcodes = data.match(/#[0-9a-f]{6}/ig);
```

hexcodes will contain

```
[
    "#3be6c4",
    "#e6e03b",
    "#6f3be6",
    "#4fe63b",
    "#e63b3b",
    "#ff5a00",
    "#ff00de",
    "#3b8fe6"
]
```

Comment: `#` belongs inside the `/` chars.

Comment: It seems to don't work with that regex. It does with this one: /\b[0-9A-F]{6}\b/gi

Answer (score 1):

It can be done without a regex as well.
Get the string content of the file, split on newlines and map the values, adding an empty string for anything that doesn't start with `#`, and then filter out the empties :

```
var arr = 'string with hex codes'.split('\n');

var hex = $.map(arr, function(color) {
    return $.trim(color).indexOf('#') === 0 ? $.trim(color).slice(0,7) : '';
}).filter(function(n) { return $.trim(n).length; });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8LebD/1/)